# [AS3]Rotate a Sprite around it's center

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation, flashdevelop

I need some help with a really specific problem.
I've looked and found some answers, but nothiung as specific as what I need.

I'm using flashdevelop, and for now, I've a rectangle (it's a Sprite) following my mouse cursor (centered).
I'd like to apply a rotation on it when I scroll my mouse wheel, but I need the rotation to apply on it's center, and I need the object to stay centered on my mouse cursor at the same time.
And I also need to apply the rotation in radians, not in degree.

For now I got this :

```
var mod:Number;

if (e.delta <= 0) {
    mod = -0.1;
}else {
    mod = 0.1;
}
```

Could someone help me with it please ? After what I've seen it seems that I've to use matrix, and complex maths, but I've no idea how to do what I want to do with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to keep the registration point of the sprite in center of the rectangle to rotate it about it's center. When you draw a sprite from (0,0) the registration point is top-left and not center. Here's how you make it center:

```
var rectangleSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
rectangleSprite.graphics.lineStyle(3,0x00ff00);
rectangleSprite.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
//please note that i am not drawing the sprite from (0,0), 
//instead i start from (-width/2,-height/2)
rectangleSprite.graphics.drawRect(-150,-75,300,150);
rectangleSprite.graphics.endFill();
```

And for degree to radian conversion you just need multiply your value in radians by (180/Math.PI) before applying your rotation.

```
var rotationInDegrees = rotationInRadians*(180/Math.PI);
```

Comment: and how can I set a registration point ? Everything I found doesn't work, it just keep my Sprite from following my mouse

Comment: also, you gave me something to turn radians in degrees, but I need the opposite.

Comment: I have edited the answer please have a look. If you need to convert degrees to radians then you will have to do var rotationInRadians= rotationInDegrees *(Math.PI/180); But i gave you the opposite coz you I thought you have all your calculations in radians, so you will have to convert them to degrees before you set the roation of the sprite. Please +1 if my answer if it was helpful

Comment: Since my Sprite follow my mouse, it's :
preview.graphics.drawRect(mouseX-(fW/2), mouseY-(fH/2), fW, fH);

where fW and fH are width and height, but it doesn't work when I'm trying the rotation :

var angleDegrees:Number = (fA * (180 / Math.PI));
preview.rotate(angleDegrees);

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Dont draw the sprite everytime on mouse move. Draw the sprite just once, add it to stage, and then on mouse move just set preview.x = mouseX and preview.y = mouseY